# Create a dynamic array of dictionaries in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I have a number of coordinate points, which exist of X, Y, Z, R floating point numbers. There could be between 3 and 15 coordinate points. For the first coordinate point, X,Y,Z,R are all zero's. As soon as I encounter the next one which are all zero's, I know that the list is done.

What I am trying to do in VBA is create a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary is one coordinate point.

I first add the first point (all zeros) outside the `For` loop and then add the next points. This is the code that I have:

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim pointsArray() As Variant
Dim point As New Dictionary
point("X") = wks.Cells(3, 6)
point("Y") = wks.Cells(3, 7)
point("R") = wks.Cells(3, 8)
point("Z") = wks.Cells(3, 9)
ReDim Preserve pointsArray(0)
Set pointsArray(0) = point

For i = 4 To 17
    Dim X As Single, Y As Single, R As Single, Z As Single
    X = wks.Cells(i, 6)
    Y = wks.Cells(i, 7)
    Z = wks.Cells(i, 8)
    R = wks.Cells(i, 9)
    If X <> 0# Or Y <> 0# Or Z <> 0# Or R <> 0# Then
        Dim p As New Dictionary
        p("X") = wks.Cells(i, 6)
        p("Y") = wks.Cells(i, 7)
        p("Z") = wks.Cells(i, 8)
        p("R") = wks.Cells(i, 9)
        ReDim Preserve pointsArray(i - 3)
        pointsArray(i - 3) = p
        Debug.Print "old"; pointsArray(i - 4)("Z")
        Debug.Print "new"; pointsArray(i - 3)("Z")
    End If
Next i
```

There are currently 4 points in the set (including the all-zero first one). But when this code is done, the three points that are added in the `For` loop are all the same. I think it has something to do with the fact that I use `Set` before I assign the new point to the list. But if I remove that I get error on the line:

```vb
pointsArray(i - 3) = p
```

Comment: `something to do with the fact that I use Set before I assign the new point to the list` - on contrary, it's because you are *not* using `Set` in `pointsArray(i - 3) = p`. You are correctly using it in `Set pointsArray(0) = point`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One thing I forgot to mention is that when I do use Set - all points in the resulting list are exactly the same, except for the first one. So my current list of 4 points will have one point which is all zeros and three points which are the same as the last one in the list - apologies for this omission in the question

Comment: If you use `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wks.Range("F4:F17"),"<>0",wks.Range("G4:G17"),"<>0",wks.Range("H4:H17"),"<>0",wks.Range("I4:I17"),"<>0")`, then you should be able to `Redim` once - *without* preserve - before the loop.  This will speed things up, and save resources.

Comment: That is because in VBA, unlike VB.NET, `Dim p As New Dictionary` declares the variable once per sub, not once per loop iteration. You need `Dim p As Dictionary` (anywhere, inside or outside the loop) and a separate `Set p = New Dictionary` inside the loop.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for your help!! It is working now. Very much appreciated.